# How do I create a mastercraft item?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I've leveled my blacksmithing up to level 10 and am now interested to see what it means to mastercraft an item. From several other places I've read, this simply indicates that I should now be able to craft epic level (purple) equipment and that the bonuses granted passively per item type should reflect that.

However, in practice, this has not been the case. Even using the highest level ingredients (e.g. Prismere Chakram Discs, Flawless secondary/optional components, and gems), the items I create still come out as green or blue, with the appropriate stats to boot.

I have noticed that adding gems to a recipe feels "odd", in that not nearly all of the gems I have in my inventory are available for crafting. Understandably so for Epic gems which are restricted to chest slot / robes, but definitely not 100% sure on how this functions.

Am I missing an essential aspect of this, or is there something more subtle that I'm just not grasping (e.g. underlying math, component types, etc.)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Every item you craft once you are at Blacksmithing level 10 is Mastercrafted.

A Mastercrafted item is not necessarily purple - it is more likely green or blue. The only difference is that a Mastercrafted item gets an additional stat added to it for free.

I tested this by creating a sword with the worst components possible - an Iron Sword (18 damage), a Crude Hilt (3 Physical Damage), and skipped all of the other components. The resulting item has a default name of "Mastercrafted Iron Longsword", is green, and had the following stats:

- 16 Physical Damage
- 5 Piercing Damage
- +3% Damage

The +3% Damage was added since I have Blacksmithing level 10 (making the item Mastercrafted).

Comment: Indeed. The color is based off of the game's percieved values for the various possible effects, similar to how some gems are more valuable than others.

Comment: +1 for testing! On a slightly related note, I'm kinda going off the assumption that the quality and quantity of additional components affects the blue/green-ness of the resulting item based on this. I have a slightly OCD vendetta against green quality items.

Comment: @TheQ I've noticed if I use all Master components and a Utility gem, the item is green. If I use the same components and a Weapon or Armor gem (depending on the slot), the item is Blue. No idea why that matters.

Comment: @Adeese I'll have to test out the gem choice then. From my experience, Chakrams/Staves get crafted with a Utility Gem as opposed to a Weapon Gem for some reason (possibly Scepters too if going by trend, but haven't tested that explicitly). However, I've definitely crafted a Blue of both Charkam/Staff varieties and used all 5 components.

Comment: @TheQ I know I've crafted a Chakram since getting BS level 10, don't recall its quality. In my original comment I was thinking of crafting armor pieces, FWIW.

Answer (score 3):

From what I've read, and I haven't attempted this to confirm it, every item in each slot has to be at least master tier in order to produce a purple item.  Not every item you create will be an epic item, but those that you do create will have noticable benefits.

Many of the items created will be blue, but will have very high stats attributed to them.

I'm also reading about people who, frustrated at attempting to salvage decent components are crafting a gem with their desired effect into junk equipment and then salvaging components from that.  The example I've seen cited is obtaining [flawless magnifying rivets by adding in gems of precision](http://forums.reckoning.amalur.com/showthread.php?5490-so-are-there-any-epic-items-out-there-then-can-make-us-happy).  [This link](http://forums.reckoning.amalur.com/showthread.php?5458-Master-Crafting-With-Gems-and-Salvaging-to-Yield-Flawless-Components!) contains a list being compiled of combinations that are producing flawless components.

Comment: I'm a tad confused then, because Flawless tier items are above Master tier items in terms of their quality. It makes sense that everything would need to be the highest tier though. Perhaps I just need to get *all* flawless items in there. The gems I'm still not sure about though.

Comment: @TheQ Are you using pristine quality gems?

Comment: Yeah, maxed out Sagecrafting as well.

Comment: Color has to deal with the price of the item, nothing more. More expensive components = more purples.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot craft purple items as these are 'unique' named items made by the developers. With the right stuff you can make blue items with pretty epic stats, but it won't be purple.
As for gems as far as I can see (so far in my game) you can only use utility gems on crafting (maybe armour, but def not wep), unless your mastercrafting chest/robe then you can add an epic gem

Answer (score 1):

When you mastercraft an item you get an extra stat to it based on type of the item. For example, mastercrafting a leather headpiece gives a +x% experience stat on it, while mastercrafting a faeblades gives a +x% damage stat etc.

Answer (score 0):

Weapon gems can go in all weapons besides Chakrams, faeblades, Septres, and Staves. Utility gems can be crafted into any piece of gear be it armor or weapons alike (even the 3 stated weapons above). And armor gems can only go into armor. Like you said, the Epics only in Chestplates when you Craft a new body armor.

Answer (score 0):

Color is determined by number of bonus types in your components regardless of quality. If all your top tier components have less than 4 different bonus types (look at the bonus picture ine circle) total, it will be green. Try adding a component with two or more bonuses or different bonus types if you really want a blue.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot create purple you read that wrong it says you can salvage purple the only way to get purple is by finding one for instance kelarics sword found stuck to a stone southeast of the first really big city that is twins with Mel sin shir were you fight the giant even me a level 35 can't make purple items and I have a master crafted longsword that does 217 damage